# Await for userlocation before calculating distance - Refactor to async function

Tags: reactjs, async-await, local-storage, geocode

In my app I need to calculate the distance between the current user and the location of events.

I used this function in previous projects and this worked for me since userlocation was determined beforehand.

In my app now it's a little bit different since the events must be filtered immediately after login on the homepage, also where userlocation is still to be determined.

So it's a matter of making my code below `asynchronous` so that calculation is started after `userLat` and `userLon` contain there values

```
const [userLat, setUserLat] = useState(localStorage.getItem('userLat'))
const [userLon, setUserLon] = useState(localStorage.getItem('userLon'))


useEffect(() => {
    data?.forEach((el) => {
      Geocode.fromAddress(
        `${el.street} ${el.houseNumber}, ${el.zip} ${el.city}`
      )
        .then((res) => {
          let dis = getDistance(
            {
              latitude: parseFloat(res.results[0].geometry.location.lat),
              longitude: parseFloat(res.results[0].geometry.location.lon),
            },
            {
              latitude: parseFloat(userLat), // Not available right away
              longitude: parseFloat(userLon), // Not available right away
            }
          );
          console.log(dis); // this return NaN since userLat & userLon values aren't available yet
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
  }, [data]);
```

So the `geocode function` should be executed as soon as `userLat` and `userLon` are available.

I have tried a few things turning it into an `async function` and trying to `await` the `userLat` en `userLon` values but without success.

Could somebody point me in the right direction about how to `wait` for `Geocode.fromAddress` until `userLat` en `userLon` values have been determined by geolocation api?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't [call hooks within conditionals](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level), you can include conditional checks within your hooks!

If you have an effect that needs to run based on `data`, `userLat`, and `userLon`, then include those as dependencies and include checks within your effect:

```js
const [userLat, setUserLat] = useState(localStorage.getItem('userLat'));
const [userLon, setUserLon] = useState(localStorage.getItem('userLon'));

useEffect(
  () => {
    // Only calculate distance if coords are available
    if (userLat && userLon) {
      data?.forEach((el) => {
        Geocode.fromAddress(`${el.street} ${el.houseNumber}, ${el.zip} ${el.city}`)
          .then((res) => {
            let dis = getDistance(
              {
                latitude: parseFloat(res.results[0].geometry.location.lat),
                longitude: parseFloat(res.results[0].geometry.location.lon),
              },
              {
                latitude: parseFloat(userLat),
                longitude: parseFloat(userLon),
              }
            );

            // Do something with `dis` here...
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      });
    }
  },
  // Re-run effect when these variables update
  [data, userLat, userLon]
);
```

Comment: Omg @romellem, stupid mistake of me! That was a solution i have tried but failed, and here is why: `res.results[0].geometry.location.lon` needed to be `res.results[0].geometry.location.lng`

Comment: But thank you very much for looking into it and confirm that this is a proper way to fix my problem. Cheers!